# VBA - Mail Merge via access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

I'm not sure why my code is not working..
I have code in vba in Access 03 which opens a word document which runs a mail merge process.
When the code runs, it asks me what the Header Delimiters are.  I specified those in the export file as a comma for a field delimiter and  as the record delimiter.  After I confirm this in word, I get a a run time error.

The error I'm getting is: 
Run-time error '5922': 
Word was unable to open the data source.

strExportFullyQualifiedName is a text file which is exported with the field names listed in there which is being used as a data source file.

I checked the links and verify, everything exists.  The connection is not being made.
strExportFullyQualifiedName is the location of the txt file.

> 

```
 With objWordDoc
        .MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
          Name:=strExportFullyQualifiedName, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
          ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdDirectory
        .MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = True
    End With
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reference to the Word Library (Code Window->Tools->References)? If not, you will need to use the values for built-in constants such as wdOpenFormatAuto

EDIT re Comment

As you have a text file, I do not believe that your types are correct. Try something like:

```
''To create output, if required
''DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "qryMailMerge", strExportFullyQualifiedName, True

 With objWordDoc
     .MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
      Name:=strExportFullyQualifiedName, Format:=wdOpenFormatText
     .MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
     .MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdDirectory
     .MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = True
 End With
```

Comment: Yes I do.  It's: 
Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library

Answer (score 1):

1. You said twice that *strExportFullyQualifiedName* is the location of a text file.  I've never automated this process before, but I thought you could only export from a *Word* file.
2. Does *strExportFullyQualifiedName* contain both the filepath & filename? e.g. "C:\Test.Doc"?

Comment: @PowerUser: the context in which the code is running is Access, not Word, no?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it matters here what the code is running in.  Mail Merge is a function in MS Word, which as far as I know, can only work with Word files.  So, his code should reference a Word file as his source.

Comment: Word mail merge can use any number of data sources, text files, Excel files, Access MDBs, etc. It doesn't need a Word file as the data *source*.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, by recording the connection macro from Word, and editing some stuff out and putting it back in Access, and it worked!